# unix commands not working

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I wanted to start developing in ruby on rails, so I followed few tutorials how to set everything needed. However, I have problem now, because basic commands in terminal window dont work. For example if I type: whoami, ls, etc... error appears saying: -bash: whomami: command not found

when I type: $PATH, this appears: -bash: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0: is a directory

did I make a mistake while setting up rails environment or it's another problem? If you have similar experiences, please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: try to run /bin/ls if its suceeded then probably your terminals environmental variables are missing

Comment: this succeeds.. how do I set terminal env vars? I dont have experiences with this.

Comment: run EXPORT PATH=/bin then try to run ls command

Comment: ls command now works, but commands like whoami,  xcode-select -p, java -version, etc.. are not working

Comment: Your system path determines in which directories bash will search to find commands that you run. Likely at some point you ran or are running `PATH=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`, where really you probably wanted to append or prepend that path to the list which includes all the default paths, like /bin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/bin, etc.  If you open a new shell, do you have the same issue, or is it just in the current shell?

Comment: when I open new terminal, it does same thing.. in current one, I set PATH to be /bin and in new one, this PATH is set back to this: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0

Comment: add this to your .bashrc file export path=/bin: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin. bashrc is a hidden file starting its name with . search for it edit it close all terminals open new one and try to run ls

Comment: I used sudo find / -name .bashrc but I didnt find this file

Comment: okey it works.. I used instead of .bashrc  - .bash_profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command.

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Better you use this command in you .bashrc file.